# SQLi : Extract MySQL data without knowing column names?

Tags: web-application, php, sql-injection, mysql

Here's the vulnerable code:

```
<?php
     $filtered = "/information|schema|_/i"; 
    #... blahblah

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$id' AND pw='$pw';"; // exist hidden column
    $query = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); 
?>
```

The information_schema table cannot be accessed, as it is filtered out of the injection.

Is there a way to extract data without knowing the column's name?

Comment: Can't you query a table you do know the columns for, in order to get the column name - specifically, one of the information_schema tables?

Comment: Since you are using "SELECT * FROM", it will extract all data from that table. All you need to do is add your SQL injection code in $pw or $id

Comment: `@mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); ` crying

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just add a condition like this:

`OR 1 = 1`

to the where clause.  For your example you could pass in a value of `test' OR '1'='1` to execute this type of attack.

Obviously if you want to *select* columns that you don't know the name of you can just specify `SELECT *...`

Comment: That's not what was asked.

Comment: Are you sure?  It seems like what he's asking.  What did you take to be the question?

Comment: `I think that there has to be a way to extract data without knowing the column's name, but how?`  The above extracts data from the table without knowing any column names.

Comment: I would assume user90711 is familiar how SQL injections work in general. What they want to know is how to get the application to leak data from a database column which is not explicitly used by the code which processes the results.

Comment: Could be.  The question really isn't clear one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, although you are a bit limited. The options are:

- all data from tables with the same number of columns as the table the orginial select selects from, provided you know the table name. The injection would be:

  ```
  ' UNION SELECT * from someOtherTable -- -.
  ```
- all data from tables with fewer column names than the amount of columns in the original table, provided there is a table with the amount of columns of the original table minus the amount of columns you want to select:

  ```
  ' UNION SELECT * from someOtherTable JOIN aThirdTable -- -
  ```
- all meta info available via functions (`version()`, `database()`, and so on).
- all data from tables where you do know the columns, eg `mysql.user`.
- You can guess column names.

The element specifying the selected columns is called a `select_expr` in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html). If you do not control the select expression of the original select, and do not know column names, and you cannot create the correct amount of columns via joins, there is - as far as I know, and as I read the documentation - no way of achieving that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can..
Assuming you know the *table name* and *union* is not blocked, you can dump that table's data.

```
MariaDB [security]> select `2` from (select 1,2,3 union select * from user)a;
```

This will dump the second column's data. What happens is that when we first select 1,2,3 before selecting the columns from the table the name of the columns is changed while returning the result. Now that you know the name of the column, it is just extraction.

So,

*/?query=' union select 1,2,(select `2` from (select 1,2,3 union select * from user)a)-- -*

would be the basic injection structure.